# Configuring Creative Sound Core 3D (CA0132) in Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: 20.04, soundcard

For years I've been trying to get sound through my speakers, to no avail. I have the Creative Sound Core 3D card and I've never had Ubuntu work right with the sound and would love some help. I figured by 20.04 there would have been a solution. I'm a Linux (and Ubuntu) noob, even though I've been using it for years. I'm a gunsmith, not a computer programmer and so I just don't remember all the lines of code I have to run in order to make stuff work.

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This is what I get with aplay (along with a LOT of NVidia devices for my monitors.) In my sound setings I can select "Line Out - Built-In Audio" and the 5.1 surround, but I get zero audio output. When I plug in my USB Corsair headset dongle I get sound from my wireless headset, but I can't get my system to work with the speakers. I know the speakers work as I'm running dual boot with Win10 and my speakers work fine there.

Comment: This was resolved thanks to the folks on the MeWe Ubuntu group "World of Ubuntu". In Alsamixer the HP Speaker setting was muted, preventing sound.

Comment: My Alienware-17-R3 with CA01232 card only play sound from internal speaker, not headphones. I tried to change Alsamixer HP Speaker option: now sound does not play at all :(

Answer (score 0):

In Alsamixer the HP Speaker setting was muted, preventing audio.